# Truffle: cannot use drizzle for communicating between react app and blockchain

Tags: truffle, drizzle

I am using `Truffle` for writing smart contract and using [drizzle](https://github.com/trufflesuite/drizzle) and [drizzle-react](https://github.com/trufflesuite/drizzle-react) for communicating with smart contract.

I have configured as tutorial said. After that, I try to print out:

```
this.props.contracts.MyContract
```

It will print a bunch of public state, public method on smart contracts ...
So I think when come to this step, there is no problem.

But when I try to call method as tutorial:

```
this.props.contracts.MyContract.methods.set(this.state.storageAmount).send()
```

I meet exception because inside `this.props.contracts.MyContract`, there is no `methods` object, so it will undefined. What am I wrong ? Please tell me.

Answer (score 1):

contracts can be accessed via context in component. make sure that you defined drizzle context types and assign contracts as `this.contracts = context.drizzle.contracts` in your component.

btw see [my pr on github](https://github.com/trufflesuite/drizzle-react/pull/23)